# GCP gpu all region quota near the limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have activated the free 300 dollars trial of google cloud platform, and successfully increase the gpu all region quota to 1, so I can create a notebook with a Tesla T4 and I've been training some models using it so far.

However, when I enter the notebook today, I found that Tesla T4 is not available, and I can't create new notebook with GPU and it says quota near limit.
[image]

My question is: is this quota limit permanent, or temporary because all GPUs are currently busy? I only used around half of my free trial dollars. Thanks!

Comment: Have you deleted the existing notebook ?

Comment: No I didn’t. That’s the weird part. Haven’t used it for a month, and when I log in today and run nvidia-smi it shows no gpu. My free trial ends next month, and it still has 100dollars credit left.

Comment: Maybe try to delete that notebook and create it again !

Comment: yep that finally works, thanks! The only downside is that all my data is gone...